# capstone disasm framework - check if argument read/written

Tags: x86, capstone

I cam using the capstone disassembly framework to disassemble intel x86 code. I need to find out which operands are read to or written from (or both). According to the website, this is possible by doing operand.access, which holds CSACREAD | CSAWRITE flags.

http://www.capstone-engine.org/op_access.html

However, if we look at the definition on github:

https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/blob/master/include/x86.h#L183

no operand[0].access exists!

What's going on? Does this feature not exist yet? Was it removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now available in the Github branch next, Capstone provides a new API named cs_regs_access().

This feature will be aviable in the version 4.0 of Capstone, you should switch to the *next* branch, that is already stable, to use it .

Comment: perfect. solved.